# Firebase Storage upload synchronously

Tags: firebase-storage

I am trying to make a upload to Firebase Storage inside a GcmTaskService. I want to make the upload synchronously but all uploads methods (putBytes, putFile...) are async.

I did not found any method to wait until the upload finishes. Is there any way to make the upload synchronously?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes there is, if you are not on the UI thread, you can block until the task completes by using the method

`com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.await(task);`