# Firebase storage wait for listeners

Tags: android, task, firebase-storage

I have a function (not inside an activity) which uploads an image to firebase storage and returns the url.
My problem is, I need to wait for the **UploadTask** to finish or else it returns me a null string. .

```
 public String pushRegisterImage(Bitmap image) {
    StorageReference imagesRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl(STORAGE_REF)
            .child(FINDMYPET).child(IMAGES).child(String.valueOf(UUID.randomUUID()));
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
    UploadTask uploadTask = imagesRef.putBytes(data);

    uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            imageUrl = null;
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Image upload error: " + e);
        }
    }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            imageUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString();
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Image uploade sucess, url: " + imageUrl);
        }
    });
    return imageUrl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem: The solution, that worked best for me, was using [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) and [CountDownLatch](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch)

Here a snippet from the code, that did the job for me. The logs here come from [Timber](https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber). It returns the downloadUrl from Firebase as a String after the task is complete but before the worker returns success.

```js
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        mFirebaseStorage = mFirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        mTriviaImageStorageReference = mFirebaseStorage.getReference().child("images");

        CountDownLatch countDown = new CountDownLatch(2);
        Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(getInputData().getString(KEY_IMAGE_URI));

        try {

        // get the image reference
        final StorageReference imageRef = mTriviaImageStorageReference.child(imageUri.getLastPathSegment());

        // upload the image to Firebase
        imageRef.putFile(imageUri).continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
            @Override
            public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    throw task.getException();
                }
                countDown.countDown();
                return imageRef.getDownloadUrl();
            }
        }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Timber.d("Image was successfully uploaded to Firebase");
                    Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                    String imageUrl = downloadUri.toString();

                    Timber.d(("URl of the image is: " + imageUrl));

                    mOutputData = new Data.Builder()
                            .putString(KEY_FIREBASE_IMAGE_URL, imageUrl)
                            .build();
                    countDown.countDown();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "upload failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    countDown.countDown();
                }
            }
        });
        countDown.await();
        return Result.success(mOutputData);

        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            Timber.e(throwable, "Error uploading image");
            return Result.failure();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.await(uploadTask);` as mentioned here: [Firebase Storage upload synchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37483300/firebase-storage-upload-synchronously). This fixed my problem (I needed to upload more files **one after another**). Also, this is not intended to be run on UIThread so make an async task or something similar.

```
final UploadTask uploadTask 
            =FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("...").putFile(path);
try {
    com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.await(uploadTask);
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Log.d("Upload", "upload took " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
```

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to synchronously put data in Firebase (and wait for result) but all interactions with Firebase Database provided by Android SDK are asynchronous (it's a real time database, which not goes well with "synchronous" things) so there is no solution to your return problem.

So answer to your question is to rethink your code and keep in mind that everything about Firebase is **asynchronous**.